# Define variable and check if it's null at once in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible simplify this

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
if(element)
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => { ... });
```

into something like this?

```
if(var element = document.getElementById('myElement'))
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => { ... });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why define a variable at all, instead of `document.getElementById('myElement')?.addEventListener()`?

Comment: I'd venture that the clarity of your first example trumps other approaches, even [the optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) approach suggested by others. By packing multiple operations into the smallest footprint, readability suffers and debugging becomes harder.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you don't have a requirement for declaring the variable, but it would be nice if you could confirm that a simplification that adds an event listener to the element if it exists is all you are looking for and that you don't actually have a requirement to also have an `element` variable declared.  Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`.

```js
document.getElementById('myElement')?.addEventListener('click', (e) => { ... });
```